# How to setup onedrive with office 365 sync for various Doc Libraries

Tags: sync, onedrive, office365, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to setup One Drive Business with Office 365 where each folder is mapped to respected Office 365 document library. For example, if I have following file share folders

```
Contracts
AFE
Agreements
Budgets
Marketing
Operations
Properties
```

I would like One Drive or One Drive Business to sync Contracts from file share to Contracts folder in Office 365 and so forth. Is it possible and how?

Thanks

Comment: OneDrive Business does not have the same feature set as the consumer level of OneDrive.

Comment: You will probably need to look at investing in SharePoint where this should be achievable.

Comment: Ramhound: Do you mean with OneDrive I can map different file share directory to sync with different 365 libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an answer to this. http://spsync.net and looks like the tool let you create different sync job per this print shot.

more on this: blog.mwiedemeyer.de/category/SPSync

http://blog.mwiedemeyer.de/post/2012/04/10/Sync-SharePoint-Document-Libraries-in-Windows-Explorer-like-Dropbox